# How can i remove option selection without value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ransack

I'm facing issues trying to remove the option or hide the first option value from a ransack code.

Could you please help me to face this issue?

I have this HTML CODE

```
<select id="q_c_0_a_0_name">
 <option value></option>
 <option value="lastanem1">First Lastname</option>
 <option value="lastname2">Second Lastname</option>
 ...
 <option value="xxxxxxxxx">Other value</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to remove option or hide the first option because Ransack gem is generating the following HTML code:

```
<select id="q_c_0_a_0_name">
 <option value="name">     Filter by Name</option>
 <option value="lastanem1">Filter by First Lastname</option>
 <option value="lastname2">Filter by Second Lastname</option>
 ...
 <option value="xxxxxxxxx">Filter by Other value</option>
</select>
```

I tried this JQuery code:

```
$(function(){
  $("#q_c_0_a_0_name option[value=]").style.display = "none";
});
```

Also tried this JQuery code:

```
$(function(){
  $("#q_c_0_a_0_name option[value=""]").style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: The jQuery code you're showing doesn't remove anything, though. You've only changed the CSS `display` property, using non-jQuery syntax. The code you're showing is equivalent to the jQuery `$("#q_.....").css("display", "none");` which doesn't remove anything. The real question is, what do you really want help with? Ransack is a server-side ruby gem, jQuery is a client-side library. Do you want to fix the source (ransack), or the result of processing the source (on-page html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) / [`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

```js
$("#q_c_0_a_0_name option:first").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="q_c_0_a_0_name">
 <option value></option>
 <option value="lastanem1">First Lastname</option>
 <option value="lastname2">Second Lastname</option>
 <option value="xxxxxxxxx">Other value</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove first option as below, whatever value it contain.

```js
$("#q_c_0_a_0_name").find("option").eq(0).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="q_c_0_a_0_name">
 <option value="name">     Filter by Name</option>
 <option value="lastanem1">Filter by First Lastname</option>
 <option value="lastname2">Filter by Second Lastname</option>
 ...
 <option value="xxxxxxxxx">Filter by Other value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the support team, this issue was making me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$("#q_c_0_a_0_name option[value='name']").remove();
```